# Average by an specific field and specific year

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents like these:

```
db.airportControl.insert({
  identification: "21c3",
  securityGateDate: new Date("2019-06-03T23:00:00Z"),
  boardingDate: new Date("2019-06-03T23:40:00Z"),
  gate: "A21",
  airportDestiny: "LAX"
});
db.airportControl.insert({
  identification: "21c3",
  securityGateDate: new Date("2019-06-04T05:00:00Z"),
  boardingDate: new Date("2018-06-04T05:21:00Z"),
  gate: "A21",
  airportDestiny: "LAX"
});
db.airportControl.insert({
  identification: "21c3",
  securityGateDate: new Date("2019-06-04T07:00:00Z"),
  boardingDate: new Date("2018-06-04T07:41:00Z"),
  gate: "A21",
  airportDestiny: "LAX"
});
db.airportControl.insert({
  identification: "21c3",
  securityGateDate: new Date("2019-06-04T07:00:00Z"),
  boardingDate: new Date("2019-06-04T07:41:00Z"),
  gate: "A21",
  airportDestiny: "TGU"
});
```

I want to know how much time passengers spend at airports, since they pass through the security gate until they board the plane by year and by airport

I have this query. I get in average how much passengers spend by airport. How can I get them by a specific year as well?, let's say 2019:

```
db.airportControl.aggregate([
  { $match: { airportDestiny: "LAX" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "",
      average: { $avg: { $subtract: ["$boardingDate", "$securityGateDate"] } }
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically requesting for two results which might be possible either by using two queries or the same thing like [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) here.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "airportDestiny": "LAX" } },
  { "$facet": {
    "totalAverage": [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "average": {
          "$avg": { "$subtract": ["$boardingDate", "$securityGateDate"] }
        }
      }}
    ],
    "averageByYear": [
      { "$match": {
        "$or": [
          { "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$boardingDate" }, 2019] }},
          { "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$securityGateDate" }, 2019]}}
        ]
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "average": {
          "$avg": { "$subtract": ["$boardingDate", "$securityGateDate"] }
        }
      }}
    ]
  }}
])
```

**Update:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "airportDestiny": "LAX",
    "$or": [
      { "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$boardingDate" }, 2019] }},
      { "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$securityGateDate" }, 2019] }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "average": {
      "$avg": { "$subtract": ["$boardingDate", "$securityGateDate"] }
    }
  }}
])
```